# Auth0 - login widget does not display enterprise connections

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, auth0

I created an Auth0 app using the starter template - Hybrid Mobile App > Ionic > ASP.NET Web API

I've followed the documentation to create an enterprise connection to my orgs IDP (Okta in this case) and I've successfully tested the connection. The login widget however, does not show this option to connect :[image: login widget]

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to add more connections to the widget. Looking at the code, the project appears to be using Auth0 angular but I don't see anything there either. I know the bootstrapped code is importing the lock library - but I don't see the lock methods called anywhere so I'm not really sure if it's using the Auth0 lock widget.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use enterprise connections with Lock, you need to associate them to one or more email domains. For example, if you're using a SAML connection:

[image]

If you type an `@example.com` email address in Lock, it will prompt you to log in with that connection directly.

If you don't want to use this feature and want to have a button to log in directly, [you can add it dynamically](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/ui-customization#adding-a-new-ui-element-using-javascript) to the list of connections. For example:

```
widget.once('signin ready', function() {
    var link = $('<a class="a0-zocial a0-sharepoint" href="#"><span>Login with Okta</span></a>');
    link.appendTo('.a0-iconlist');
    link.on('click', function() {
        widget.getClient().login({connection: 'your-okta-connection-name'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that little blurb there. I even read it - my brain didn't connect the dots. For some reason I was thinking about the Heroku login widget when I read that.